# Select one property from Map.values()

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I would like to have something like this:

```js
let myMap = new Map<string, any>();

myMap.set("aaa", {a: 1, b: 2, c:3});
myMap.set("bbb", {a: 1, b: 2, c:6});
myMap.set("ccc", {a: 1, b: 2, c:9});

let cs = myMap.values().map(x => x.c);
```

Selecting the c property from all entries from the map. This is failing with:

```js
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IterableIterator<any>'.
```

Any elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()` to turn any iterable into an array:

```js
let myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("aaa", {a: 1, b: 2, c:3});
myMap.set("bbb", {a: 1, b: 2, c:6});
myMap.set("ccc", {a: 1, b: 2, c:9});

// Basic example
let cs = Array.from( myMap.values() ).map(x => x.c);

console.log( cs );

// Array.from also takes a mapping function as the second parameter, so even shorter:

let cs_alt = Array.from( myMap.values(), x => x.c );

console.log( cs_alt );
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!